# error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Reference isn't valid.'

Tags: c#, excel

Why I got this bug: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:` 'Reference isn't valid.';

on this code:

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace testing7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Import()
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = true;

            dynamic file1Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path\file1.xlsx");
            dynamic file2Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path\file2.xlsx");

            dynamic file1Worksheet = file1Workbook.Sheets[1];

            dynamic columnJ = file1Worksheet.Columns["J:J"];
            columnJ.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C[-1],'[file2.xlsx]Feuil1'!C1:C3,3,0),\"\")";

            dynamic rangeJ1 = file1Worksheet.Range["J1"];
            rangeJ1.AutoFill(file1Worksheet.Range["J1:J551"]);

            dynamic columnH = file1Worksheet.Columns["H:H"];
            columnH.Cut(file1Worksheet.Columns["K:K"]);

            dynamic rangeM1 = file1Worksheet.Range["M1"];
            dynamic consolidateRange = file1Worksheet.Range["C10:C11"];
            rangeM1.Consolidate(consolidateRange, Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum, true, true, false);

            rangeM1.Value = "Tools";

            dynamic rangeN1 = file1Worksheet.Range["N1"];
            rangeN1.Value = "Units";

            dynamic rangeMN = file1Worksheet.Range["M:N"];
            rangeMN.Copy();

            dynamic newWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            dynamic newWorksheet = newWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

            newWorksheet.Range["A1"].PasteSpecial();

            excelApp.CutCopyMode = 0;

            string savePath = @"C:\Users\CHAIMAE EL GUENNOUNI\Downloads\correct folder\newWorkbook.xlsm";
            newWorkbook.SaveAs(savePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled);

            file1Worksheet.Range["M:N"].ClearContents();

            file1Worksheet.Columns["K:K"].Cut(file1Worksheet.Columns["H:H"]);
            file1Worksheet.Columns["J:J"].ClearContents();

            file1Workbook.Close();
            file2Workbook.Close();

            excelApp.Quit();
        }

        private void BtImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Import();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to extract data from 2 excel files by using some formulas and the consolidate method and when I ran it,  this message appeared: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Reference isn't valid.'`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.